# How to avoid duplicate "using" code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wcf, transactions

I have a wcf api and wish to wrap all requests inside a transaction

Currently my code looks like this in each endpoint

```
public MyCompleteList ReadOrganisations()
    {
        MyCompleteList resp = new MyCompleteList ();
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    DC_Base browser_request = new DC_Base(PROJECT);
                    browser_request.cmd_user_id = coreDb.GetUserIDFromLoginName(PROJECT,
                        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                    resp =
                        new MyCompleteList (coreSc.User_Read_All_Organisations(browser_request, utils,
                            validation, coreSc, coreDb));
                    scope.Complete();
                }
                else
                {
                    resp.SetResponseNotLoggedIn();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
        {
            resp.SetResponseServerError();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            resp.SetResponseServerError();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

As you can see if I am to use the "using" transaction scope part in every endpoint (approx 300) its going to be a lot of duplicated code.

**is there anyway to reduce the amount of duplication?**

Comment: Yeah create a parent class, move your code in there.

Comment: how do you mean? can you provide some more details currently this wcf service inherits from an interface to base class to then to a top level class what do you mean by adding a parent class? these functions are called by external clients aka via json

Comment: Your question is not very clear - how is "using" causing duplication of code?

Comment: if i want to use a transaction in each endpoint call from a client, then I will need to put using (....) in every endpoint which is alot of duplication the sample is just one of many endpoints offered by our api

Comment: Read some articles about *Aspect-Oriented Programming* and *Interception*.

Comment: Also, please don't use SERIALIZABLE transactions with SQL Server.  Change the TransactionScope to READ COMMITTED.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the comment its very good information

Answer (score 2):

You can write a helper method, that handles the transaction logic while calling your actual code as a lambda.

```
    public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func, TransactionExecutionOptions options = null)
    {
        options = options ?? TransactionExecutionOptions.Default;

        T res;
        using (var tx = new TransactionScope(options))
        {
            res = func();
            tx.Complete();
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Depending on your needs you can provide additional arguments to the `Func` argument; for example, the `Execute` method could also open a database connection and pass that to the func (then having `Func<IDbConnection, T>` as parameter type). YMMV.

For your example:

```
public MyCompleteList ReadOrganisations()
{
    MyCompleteList resp = new MyCompleteList ();
    try
    {
        resp = Execute(() => {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                DC_Base browser_request = new DC_Base(PROJECT);
                browser_request.cmd_user_id = coreDb.GetUserIDFromLoginName(PROJECT,
                    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                resp =
                    new MyCompleteList (coreSc.User_Read_All_Organisations(browser_request, utils,
                        validation, coreSc, coreDb));
                scope.Complete();
            }
            else
            {
                resp.SetResponseNotLoggedIn();
            }
       });
    }
    catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
    {
        resp.SetResponseServerError();
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
        resp.SetResponseServerError();
    }
    return resp;
}
```

If possible, you can also factor the `SetResponse*()` methods out into a base class or interface (say IMyResponse), thus making it possible to handle this aspect inside the `Execute` method as well.

```
    public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func, TransactionExecutionOptions options = null) where T : IMyResponse
    {
        options = options ?? TransactionExecutionOptions.Default;

        T res;
        try
        {
            using (var tx = new TransactionScope(options))
            {
                res = func();
                tx.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
        {
            res.SetResponseServerError();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            res.SetResponseServerError();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: ok this looks like what I was thinking about I can give it a test thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes i have the responses already in interfaces which all responses inherit from so this looks even better

Answer (score 1):

1- Create a ServiceBase class as follows

```
public class ServiceBase
    {

       protected void ExecuteOperation(Action codetoExecute)
        {                               
            try
            {               
                 using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {                   
                    codetoExecute.Invoke();             
                    scope.Complete();                
                }                           
            }
            catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
            {
                // handle exception
            }
            catch (ApplicationException ex)
            {
                // handle exception
            }            
        }
    }
```

2- Each new service must inherits from ServiceBase and call ExecuteOperation instead. Code as follows:

```
ExecuteOperation(() =>
            {                 
                 // Custom code here
            });
```

3- Atomic transactions are useful when executing operations that dont expect results in return.